# How to use wiringpi?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sensors, i2c, wiringpi

I'm using raspberry pi 3 b+ and si7021 to get temperature and humidity. But now I have a problem that I don't know how to use wiringpi correctly.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import time
import wiringpi

I2C_ADDR = 0x40
SI7021_REG_NO_HOLD_HUMIDITY = 0xF5
SI7021_REG_NO_HOLD_TEMPERATURE = 0xF3


wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()
fd = wiringpi.wiringPiI2CSetup(0x40)
#fd = wiringpi.wiringPiI2CSetupInterface("/dev/i2c-0", I2C_ADDR)
while True:
    try:
        print(wiringpi.wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,0x40,0xF3))
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print(fd, wiringpi.wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x40))
       # print(wiringpi.wiringPiI2CRead(0x40))
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

The problem is I will always get 0 or negative value after `wiringpi.wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,0x40,0xF3)` and `wiringpi.wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x40)` executed. According to their manual, this means an error.

I'm quite sure that my connection is correct since I can use `i2cget` to get a correct value. Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the Linux kernel driver for your chip: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/humidity/si7020.c?

Comment: @0andriy Thank you for your response. I'm studying Iot so I prefer to program by myself instead of using some libraries off the shelf. But whatever, thank you for your help!

Comment: Drivers in the kernel are written on purpose, but good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 0):

The slave address that is mentioned in the [datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf) is already passed to the wiringpi library in the `wiringPiI2CSetup(0x40)` call. You do not need to repeat it, it is implicitly passed as `fd`. Given the [wiringpi documentation](http://wiringpi.com/reference/i2c-library/) you‘re trying to set register 0x40 to value 0xF3. Instead you should use `wiringPiI2CWrite` to issue the command. And similarly use `wiringPiI2CRead` afterwards.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your reply. I tried your advice, but it still doesn't work, the result of `wiringPiI2CWrite` is 0 while the result of `wiringPiI2CRead` is -1 as usual.

Comment: What does `errno` tell you?

Comment: This is the weirdest part because it only replies a number without anything else. I didn't even know it was an error number before I checked wiringpi's website.

Comment: C libraries have the convention to return a boolean (ok or not ok) and then use a side channel like `errno` to convey further info. So what does `errno` say? According to the datasheet, I‘d expect a NACK error, as you‘re querying in „no hold“ mode. Repeat until you get the measurement value (p. 19ff)